Find is the value of the radius "x" in the circle below as a function of R and r
What is the value of the radius $"x"$ in the circle below?
(Answer: $\frac{r}{R}(R-r)$)

I try:
$\triangle OMN:(R-2r)^2+MN^2=R^2$
$R^2-4Rr+4r^2+MN^2=R^2$
$MN^2=4Rr-4r^2$
$MN^2 = 4r(R-r)$
I can't see which geometric figure to use the $x$ in.


Draw $CD\perp OA$ , $DE$ and radius through $OD$
then $OC=R-2r+x$ , $OD=R-x$ and $DE=r+x$
Since $\triangle OCD$ and $\triangle CED$  are a right triangles
$DE^2=EC^2+CD^2$
$(r+x)^2=(r-x)^2+CD^2$ then $CD^2=4rx$
and
$OD^2=OC^2+CD^2$
$(R-x)^2 = (R+x-2r)^2 + 4rx$
$R^2 -2Rx + x^2 = R^2 + x^2 +4r^2 + 2Rx - 4Rr - 4rx + 4rx$
$Rx=Rr-r^2$
$x=\frac{r}{R} (R-r)$

Let $P$ be the center of the $r$ circle, $Q$ be the center of the $x$ circle and $H$ its projection on $OA$. Then we have two equations:
$$
QH^2=(R-x)^2-(R-2r+x)^2 \quad\text{(triangle $OQH$)}\\
QH^2=(r+x)^2-(r-x)^2  \quad\text{(triangle $PQH$)}\\
$$
Eliminating $QH$ gives an equation which can be solved for $x$.
